# Keeping a subview from being hidden by the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview

In my View Controller I have a `UIView` as a subview that has a `UITextView` subview. The `UIView` subview stays above the keyboard. As a user types into the `UITextView` the subview's height will expand.

How can I keep the subview from going under the navigation bar? So basically once it reaches the navigation bar keep it pinned there. If I backspace or delete my text then the subview will go back to it's original height.

Comment: Do you think you could attach a picture to show us what’s going on? Right now your question is hard to understand.

Comment: There is a view that is on top of the keyboard that has a UITextView. As the user types that view expands or it's height expands upwards towards the top. Once it reaches the UINavigationBar the view is hidden behind it. How do I pin that view to the bottom of the UINavigationBar when it reaches that?

Comment: Why not just use a constraint?

Comment: That’s what I’m thinking just making sure i do it correct. Basically I want to do what iMessage does.